# push data into object into array php

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

Well, I have an array that contains objects inside.

it's something like this...

```
[{"name"=>"Pepe"},
 {"name"=>"Jane"},
 {"name"=>"Max"},
 {"name"=>"Mishelle"},
 {"name"=>"Petter"},
 {"name"=>"George"},
 {"name"=>"Maria"}]
```

What I'm trying to do is make a **for** loop and in each iteration insert, for example, a last name for each first name. The Array should be something like this...

```
[{"name"=>"Pepe",
  "last_name","smith"},
 {"name"=>"Jane",
  "last_name","jhonson"},
 {"name"=>"Max",
  "last_name","valdez"},
 {"name"=>"Mishelle",
  "last_name","smith"},
 {"name"=>"Petter",
  "last_name","planck"},
 {"name"=>"George",
  "last_name","smith"},
 {"name"=>"Maria",
  "last_name","kennedy"}]
```

This is make with PHP

```
$data = DB::table('guia_sucursal')
    ->join('colecciones','colecciones.id','=','guia_sucursal.coleccion_id')
    ->join('sucursales','colecciones.sucursal_destino_id','=','sucursales.id')
    ->select('colecciones.id as id','colecciones.titulo as titulo','colecciones.image as url','colecciones.codigo_barra as code_bar','sucursales.nombre as sucursal_destino')
    ->groupBy('guia_sucursal.coleccion_id')
    ->distinct('guia_sucursal.coleccion_id')
    ->get();

    foreach ($data as $coleccion){
        $num = 1;
        array_push($coleccion, "sucursal"=>"SUCURSAL".$num);

        $num = $num +1;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried making the `for` loop? Can you post what you tried?

Comment: ready, I added an example of what I want to do, although obviously what I need is more complex, but if I can add a new value to that object, I would have everything solved

Comment: It is not clear where your `last_name` is magically coming from.  How can we know which `last_name` to pair with the `name`?  Is this found in the database results?  Why isn't there a `WHERE` clause in the query to ensure that a correct relationship is made?  I find this question to be Unclear.  If your question is basically asking how to add a property to an array of objects, then this question is a duplicate.

Comment: the last name was not important, it could be anyone, what I wanted was to add the field "last_name" the value of that field did not matter what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
/* This is not valid php code, you copied it from var_dump or something,
    users = {"name"=>"Pepe"},
 {"name"=>"Jane"},
 {"name"=>"Max"},
 {"name"=>"Mishelle"},
 {"name"=>"Petter"},
 {"name"=>"George"},
 {"name"=>"Maria"}
]
*/

foreach($users as $user){
    $user->last_name = 'Last name of user';
}
```

But you haven't provided information about "last_name" data.

Do you have 2 arrays, one containing "name" and other containing "last_name"?

*** Edit**
Question:  "*What I really need is to know how to add a new field and its respective value to an Object.*"

```
class User {
    public $name;
    public $last_name;
}

$user = new User;

$user->name = "Jake";
$user->last_name = "Li";
```

Since you are fetching data from database, adding data like this will not store it in database after script is finished.

Let's create array of objects like you have in example above

```
$users = [
    new User,
    new User,
];
```

Which is essentialy:

```
/* 
    $users = [
        {},
        {}
    ];
*/
```

Now we have $users array of 2 user objects.

To add properties to those users we simply like in above example use: ' -> '

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $user->name = 'Max';
    $user->last_name = 'Maxximus';
}
```

So every $user in array now has name='Max' and last_name='Maxximus'

Comment: The syntax shown here does not actually work, to manipulate the contents of $users outside of the foreach loop - foreach works on a _copy_ of the array. This either needs passing of the value ($user) via reference, or explicit access of the items via the array variable name and the key.